# How can I determine current directory of executing YAML pipeline in azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, relative-path

We have a large Azure DevOps monorepo, containing many applications and YAML pipelines.
We try to maximise autonomy of our solutions, so we define pipelines in a `\Pipelines\` sub directory within the solution root directory. The solutions are in various depths from the repo root.

Every time we need to reference a source file from YAML to pass it to a built-in task such as [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops), [DotNetCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) or [NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops), we refer to it as relative to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`, which seems to indicate the repo root. For example, to pass `my-solution.sln` to a task, we refer to it as `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\path\to\my-solution.sln`. This works, but makes the relation between the pipeline and the solution less atomic, as it requires to explicitly define the full path from the repo root to the solution. If a solution ever moves as a whole unit (which happens), this unit breaks if we don't update the YAML file. This as opposed to most other entities within our ecosystem (in our case .Net), which refer to other entities (e.g. solution --> project; project --> referenced project) by relative path from the source location.

**My question:**

Is there any pipeline variable (or any other accessible variable e.g. environment variable) which captures the location of the currently executing YAML pipeline? Or is that information lost when Azure compiles the pipelines for execution?

If there is no such variable, is there any other (simple) way to retrieve said location? I understand that I can query the Azure DevOps API, but this seems like it would add more code and maintenance than it would save in the long run.

I've looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), but if any of those is what I want, then I must have missed it.

Answer (score 0):

> Every time we need to reference a source file from YAML to pass it to a built-in task such as MSBuild, DotNetCLI or NuGet, we refer to it as relative to $(Build.SourcesDirectory), which seems to indicate the repo root. For example, to pass my-solution.sln to a task, we refer to it as $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\path\to\my-solution.sln.

You can still use related path, don't need have to use full path. Accoridng to the folder/file structure, use `../` to **parent folder**, use `./` as **current folder**. For example:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: ../Bank/Bank.csproj    # related path
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

In DevOps pipeline, your source code will be checked out to agent machine, by default it's `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` which points to `c:\agent_work\1\s` for example. The pipeline tasks are executed with the files(source code) under this folder. Unless you define `workingDirectory` for some tasks, please check the doc description below:

[image]

In addition, DevOps support "[File matching patterns reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops)", you can specify `**/*.proj` to match the files.

Hope it answers.

Comment: Had the same question, but did not find it answered here: In my understanding, `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` equates to `/` in my repository, but my yaml file might be in `/projects/my-fancy-app/fancy-app-pipeline.yaml`. So how do I get the path of the yaml file, which is `/projects/my-fancy-app`, during runtime?